# Attach debugger to another instance of Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am attempting to attach to another instance of visual studio 2017 to debug random VS crashes, usually when in the winforms designer.  The techniques to do this in VS2012 and earlier are not working.

I have tried starting as administrator and using the /rootsuffix Exp command line argument. The other instance of VS does load but I cannot set any breakpoints in my code "because no symbols are loaded".

The last time I tried this was in VS2012 and it worked perfectly. Is there a new "trick" to doing this in VS2017?  Note I have also tried with VS2015 with no success.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to spin up the process in the first instance of VS, and the detach the process ( Debug > Detach All ). Then in the second VS instance attach t the process ( Debug > Attach to Process ).

Comment: The process is VS itself. It keeps crashing ("Visual studio is restarting") when I load a winform into the designer. In the past, I could debug using another instance of VS and put a break point at the top of the Initialize() method to see which control was causing the exception.